# TypeError: cannot convert key of dictionary on call to prediction?

Tags: cntk

I'm trying to do 10 test predictions similar to the code in the CNTK_103B_MNIST_FeedForwardNetwork tutorial, but I'm getting an error as shown below. What could be the problem with my code?

Code / Error Message

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question. I used the incorrect name of the CNTK input_variable in the model.

I changed this line of code:

```
predicted_label_prob = pred_basic_model.eval({input : x})
```

to

```
predicted_label_prob = pred_basic_model.eval({pred_basic_model.arguments[0] : x})
```

and now it works.